# how to enable DPRP in PayPal Sandbox account?

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I am calling "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile' method to create recurring payments on CreditCard. But, I am getting 11586 "DPRP is disabled for this merchant". I have been searching through all related threads but none of them is working. I created a fresh US Business Pro account and it did not work either. Some claims that I can enable it from "Products & Services" tab but that tab does not have any "Recurring Payments" link (others does not have any related option).

So, I am kinda stuck. none of my 3 business pro account (both old and new) are working. Anyone know how to get around this? just for information, I am using NVP Classic PayPal API on a sandbox business account.  I can provide any information you want to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox pages tend to mirror their live counterparts. You can typically just change "www.paypal.com" to "www.sandbox.paypal.com".

So here's the link to DPRP on the Sandbox site [DPRP](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=xpt/Marketing/general/ProRecurringPayments-outside). What I would do is log into your sandbox account and hit that sign up page and go through the process. That should flag your Sandbox for DPRP.

Comment: that DPRP did open up on sandbox account but when I click on "Signup" button I get weired PayPal error Message 3005 "Sorry — your last action could not be completed" in black and red text.

Comment: Strange. You might have to talk to MTS then to get it resolved. https://ppmts.custhelp.com/ That trick usually works for me but it's been a while since I did that.

Comment: I tried phone but they said Sandbox questions are entertained only through online form and its been 3 days I got no reply from them. :(

Answer (score -1):

To enable this option for sandbox contact  [paypal tech support](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask). Here is an tech support answer:

> At the moment this feature can be enabled only by us. We have submitted feature request to our developer team to allow this feature to be enabled automatically by customers.