# Payment error: PayPal error: DPRP is disabled for this merchant sandbox account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I'm working on a nopCommerce project, and I want to use PayPal recurring payment option with sandbox merchant sandbox account.

For that I've created PayPal developer(business for sandbox)account and configured PayPal direct Plugin.

But at the time of payment, it gives me an error of:

```
Payment error: PayPal error: DPRP is disabled for this merchant. (DPRP_DISABLED)
```

Also enabled Pro feature for my merchant account.

[image]

I saw this forum and other sites as well, but didn't get solution to solve this issue, all answers pointed out to upgrading pro with $60 USD

I'm really wondering, PayPal charge for sandbox business account?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184150/how-to-enable-dprp-in-paypal-sandbox-account

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for the link, trying to do that

Comment: @CBroe: At the end, for active account they are asking for credit card information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPRP = Direct Payment Recurring Payments.

PayPal charges $30/mo for PayPal Pro itself, and then an additional $30/mo for Recurring Payments for Pro.  It sounds like you have Pro enabled, but not Recurring Payments.

PayPal does not charge any fee to use Pro in the sandbox, but you do need to create a sandbox seller account with Pro activated on it along with recurring billing.  You can get this enabled by contact PayPal MTS.